# Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'IexBaseExc.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, path, include

So I have added this path to my Include files in C/C++ general section however I still get this error. What's the fix for Visual Studio 2015 in Windows 10?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'IexBaseExc.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file replay\replay_renderer.cpp)  renderdoc   c:\users\mona\playing-for-data\renderdoc\renderdoc\3rdparty\openexr\openexr\ilmimf\ImfHeader.h  55
```

[image]

[image]

I have cleaned the project and built it again!

Comment: Well, have you checked that the file actually exists where you *think* it is at?

Comment: yes, it exists in that directory

Comment: The directory listing you are showing is not the directory you've specified in the Additional Include directories.

Comment: well, if you look more carefully you see that it is `C:\Users\mona\playing-for-data\renderdoc\renderdoc\3rdparty\openexr\IlmBase\Iex` @AnonMail

Comment: My bad.  It seems correct.  But see below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Aditional Include Directories` can be specified per `Configuration` and `Platform`. On your screenshot you set include directory for *Profile* configuration and *Win32* platform.

Check that proper include directory value set for configuration and platform you are building for. Active configuration can be found in `Configuration Manager`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your .Vcxproj file by search path in it. If what you added got included. Sometimes Visual studio doesn't do that.

Now I solved it in two ways.

First, I manually added the include path into .vcxproj
Problem with that you need at least one include path already in the .Vcxproj else it may break the project settings of not done careful.

Second, don't know why it works. Instead of setting the include for a specific platform and configuration. Choose all configuration and all platform. Then add your paths. This worked for me well. Still works.

See if that helps.